# Move a specific number of files to folders from a large pool of files

Tags: files

I have 1 million files in a single folder (source). I want to create a new folder, move 5K files into it and repeat until all files in source are moved over to separate destination folders. The end result would be 200 new folders with 5K files each. I want to do this in Windows preferably.

The folder names can be randomly created, the files can be randomly picked from the pool.

Update 1: The resulting 200 folders will live directly under root, so no destination folder structure is needed.

Comment: Powershell is a better option than Cygwin, but well ok, your question is not precise enough...Not sure where to start here...just move those files c:\source\*.* to x:\dest ??

Comment: If the filenames are truly random, or something like a GUID, a common way of doing this is, say for the file ABCDEFG.jpg to move it to `\AB\CD\ABCDEFG.jpg`

Comment: This is a point of view...i was thinking that if a new folder is required for each 5K files, then `\1` for first 5000 files, then `\2` for next 5000 files and so on...

Comment: @krisFR I'm good with any folder name as long as the source files are equally moved over to 200 separate folders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer what you want exactly, this will move 5,000 files into folders, starting with `1` and continuing until it runs out of files to move. Your last folder will most likely have less than 5,000 files in it.

In powershell, untested, so YMMV.

```
$filesperfolder = 5000
$sourcePath = "C:\Temp"
$destPath = "C:\Temp\Sorted"
$i = 0;
$folderNum = 1;

Get-ChildItem "$sourcePath\*.pdf" | % {

    New-Item -Path ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum) -Type Directory -Force
    Move-Item $_ ($destPath + "\" + $folderNum);

    $i++;

    if ($i -eq $filesperfolder){
        $folderNum++;
        $i = 0 ;
    }
}
```

---

This isn't in line with what you've asked *exactly*, but a common way of dealing with this issue is to break the files into two more depths, based on the first characters in the filename.

This does not distribute the files evenly, but if the files are named with GUIDs, you'll have a limit of 256 folders at each level.

In Powershell, to sort out `*.pdf` from `c:\temp` to `c:\temp\sorted`:

```
$sourcePath = "C:\Temp"
$destPath = "C:\Temp\Sorted"
Get-ChildItem "$folderPath\*.PDF" | %{
    $newFolder = $destPath + ("\" + $_.Name.SubString(0,2) + "\"  + $_.Name.SubString(3,2)).ToUpper();

    New-Item -Path $newFolder -Type Directory -Force
    Move-Item $_ $newFolder
}
```

Comment: `but a common way of dealing with this issue is to break the files into two more depths, based on the first characters in the filename` Ha ? could you expand ?

Comment: @krisFR sure. This is something I've done more times than I care to think about. Multiple times I find a directory with millions of files, and each file is just a GUID + extension as its filename. So to make sure you have a sane directory structure you have two depths of subfolders (instead of just one as the op is proposing). So `A9658938.jpg` gets sorted into `A9\65\A9658938.jpg`. If they are GUIDs then you'll never have more than 256 folders per level.

Comment: Maybe I'm phrasing it poorly. My brain is sort of mush this morning.

Comment: No no that is great, but what's the gain with that against a dedicated folder for each 5000 files, based on count number ? I don't think you can get exactly 200 folders at the end with this logic. You will have a lot of subfolders resulting in an unreadable tree structure at the end...

Comment: @krisFR no, you won't, so it solves a slightly different problem, but I think solves it nicer.

Comment: @krisFR the folders are less readable, but the advantage is if you have _just_ a filename, you know exactly which sub folder it will be in, because the folder path is derived from the filename. By just dumping them in folders, you can't derive its location without scanning all those folders and essentially scanning 5 million filenames to find it. This may or may not be an issue, depending on what the op is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: For example, I use this method when I have the files in the folder, and a reference to that filename in a database field. Run that script to move them, run an SQL script to update the filename in the database, bam, done.

Comment: This is an absolute good point of view and good practice that i am agree with, depending on context. It all depends about OPs contraints. My heart leads me to your edit about counting, as far as i can understand the OPs contraints :)

Comment: I'd like to have only one level of destination folders and equal number of files please.

Comment: @Regmi I'm not a script writing service. I'm sure you can adjust the script that I've given to make it work that way.

Comment: The script runs good for 1500 source files. It stalls when running against 600K files. I'll do some diagnostics and report. (no output, no moving of files)

Comment: Server had some memory issues - works now, thanks.

Comment: For the first script: Make sure to remove the *.pdf qualifier or replace with the extensions you want to target & make sure that your current working dir is the "source folder".